# iOS: Updating tableViewCell infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, uitableview

This is the problem: I update my tableview after saving and fetching an thumbnail to Core Data and then I tell the cell to update itself - so it can show a thumbnail when the image has been loaded into Core Data. I Use two different threads as Core Data is not threadsafe and all GUI elements of course needs to happen in the main thread.

But this whole method just keep looping forever, and what is causing it is when I reload the thread:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Why? and how do I fix this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Photo"];
    Photo *photo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    cell.textLabel.text = photo.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = photo.subtitle;

    NSLog(@"Context %@", self.photographer.managedObjectContext);
    [self.photographer.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        [Photo setThumbnailForPhoto:photo];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.thumbnail];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        });
    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: DO NOT, i repeat, DO NOT call a reload table(cell) function inside the cellforrowatindexpath.. Because it will fetch the image over and over. When you reload the tableview or any cell it will call the cellforrowatindexpath again (and again and again in your case)

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called just before drawing the cell. So it is already updated. Why do you need to reload in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Mert: I just though I should reload it there since I got access to the tableViewCell directly there.

Answer (score 3):

The infinite loop is caused by calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again after the fetch is loaded and the reload on a certain cell is called.

A reload will force the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called again... and in your case again and again to infinity.

The solution is simple... Do not reload your cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but rather in a callback-method of the fetchrequest. Then reload it there rather then the creation of the cell.

Rather do not load the image inside the `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` at all.
Whenever your table is instantiated make a method that loops over your datasource and get the respective cell for each item. Then load an image for each cell you deem needed. And reload the cell whenever the fetching of the item is done (for instance a callback method).

If you do want the image to be loaded inside the creation of the cell as you have done now (Although I don't think that is the proper way to do it). You can surround the whole performBlock: with an if-statement checking if the image has already been set or not.

Comment: That sounds great! but... I just realized I have no idea what a callback method is...

Comment: A callback method is a method that is called whenever your fetchresult is done. In this case getting an image. Thing is, you need to do the loading of the images outside the cellForRowIndexpath

Comment: He's doing an async dispatch to the main queue as the callback already though.

Comment: Exactly, that is were you do a callback-method for instance. Or just put the reloading of the code which I don't think is proper coding.
Main thing is, the problem will be solved when the loading of the image is done outside the cellForRowAtIndexpath: (which is what I'm saying again and again)

Comment: But he'd still keep calling out to this infinitely if all he did was replace the dispatch with a method (although I might be ignorant as to how NSmanagedObjectContext performBlock works)

Comment: You misunderstand. What he needs to do is get the entire loading of the image OUTSIDE the cellForRowAtIndexpath:.. Read the answer fully, please

Comment: So you're saying the flow should be: `cellForRow` starts the photo update, and if the update actually changes the property then the fetched results controller callback will cause the reload? I got confused and started thinking fetch request callback meant 'callback for downloading the image' but I see how that approach would work.

Comment: You can start the download in the cellforrow but its not good coding imo. You can fix that with an if-statement. However you should fetch all images OUTSIDE the cellforrow and insert them in the tableview in the callback of that fetch and then reload the cellrow/tableview.

Answer (score 1):

As already been said by others, there should be no need to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` when the image has been loaded. Assigning a new image to `cell.imageView.image` is sufficient.

But there is another problem with your code. I assume that `self.photographer.managedObjectContext` is a managed object context of the "private concurrency type", so that `performBlock` executes on a background thread. (Otherwise there would be no need to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)`.)

So `performBlock:` executes the code asynchronously, on a background thread. (Which is good because the UI is not blocked.) But when the image has been fetched after some time, the cell might have been *reused* for a different row. (This happens if you scroll the table view so that the row becomes invisible while the image is fetched.)

Therefore, you have to check if the cell is still at the same position in the tableview:

```
[self.photographer.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    [Photo setThumbnailForPhoto:photo];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqualTo:indexPath]) {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.thumbnail];
        }
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace the following code:

```
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.thumbnail];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

With:

```
    UITableViewCell *blockCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    blockCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.thumbnail];
    [blockCell setNeedsLayout];
```

This solves the issue of reloading recursively, as well as the possibility that `cell` has gotten reused in the interim. I'd also check for whether or not you've loaded the photo data already and not update if so.

Since you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` though, you may be better off going with Totomus Maximus' answer, if the delegate callbacks are already informing you when the photo data updates. This way just updates the image view and wouldn't update any other information that the Photo update method could change.